# C++ program to find min/max of inputted numbers

Tags: c++

I need to create a C++ program that finds the min and max of a certain set of numbers the user inputs. However I am having trouble getting the min and max correct. I've searched through stack overflow already but we haven't gone over  yet and my professor requires us to use if statements to generate the program and not any pre-existing functions.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() 
{
  int counter = 0;
  int digit;
  int numdigits;
  int min = 0;
  int max = 0;

  cout << "How many integers would you like to enter?" << endl;
  cin >> numdigits;

  if ( numdigits == 1 )
  {
      cout << "Please enter " << numdigits << " integer." << endl;
  }
  else if ( numdigits > 1 )
  {
      cout << "Please enter " << numdigits << " integers." << endl;
  }

  for ( counter = 0 ; counter < numdigits ; counter++ )
      cin >> digit;

  if ( digit > max )
      max = digit;

  if ( digit < min )
      min = digit;;

  cout << "min: " << min << endl;
  cout << "max: " << max << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I was using VIM before but have switched to CLion. I'm a brand new CS student and I work full time, fully aware my code isn't that good, bear with me. Output works fine but I get '0' as minimum every time regardless of numbers. Any other advice on my code I appreciate!

Comment: terrible names for vars, especially if `using namespace std;` is somewhere in your code base.

Comment: I'd suspect doing `counter++;` twice for each loop iteration isn't intentional.

Comment: What output are you getting? What output are you expecting? Please post your complete code, i imagine the bug is in the code you haven't posted

Comment: You aren't using braces for your for loop, so the only thing in the loop is `cin >> digit;`. The rest gets executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues in your code.

The first is that you have not included braces on your for loop so if max/min statements aren't evaluated inside the for loop. The corrected code is:

```
for ( counter = 0 ; counter < numdigits ; counter++ )
{
    cin >> digit;

    if ( digit > max )
    {
        max = digit;
    }

    if ( digit < min )
    {
        min = digit;;
    }
}
```

It is good practice to always use braces for loops and if statements unless you put the statement on a single line as this prevents bugs when you add a second line to the body of the statement and forget to add the braces. For example:

```
if ( a ) std::cout << "test";
```

Is safe but:

```
if ( a )
   std::cout << "test";
```

Is very easy to accidentally modify to:

```
if ( a )
   std::cout << "test";
   std::cout << "test2";
```

The second issue in your code is the initialisation of min and max. As min is set to 0 it will only reduce when you enter a number less than 0. As max is also set to 0 it wont produce the correct answer if you only enter negative numbers. The solution is to initialise min to a number larger than your possible inputs and initialise max to a number smaller than your possible inputs. The correct way to do this in c++ is to use `std::numeric_limits`:

```
#include <limits>

int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

This sets min to `2^31-1` and max to `-2^31` (assuming you are using a platform with 32-bit integers) which means that any possible input you can enter will give you the correct answer.

The final issue is that you aren't checking that your reads from `std::cin` were successful. For example if you type a letter instead of a number as input your program will continue and not ask for another number. The corrected code for asking for `numdigits` could look like this:

```
int numdigits = 0;
while ( numdigits == 0 )
{
  cout << "How many integers would you like to enter?" << endl;
  cin >> numdigits;
  if ( !cin.good() )
  {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore();
      cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
      numdigits = 0;
  }
}
```

You'll need to make the same correction when reading `digit`.

Answer (score -4):

The biggest issue is that your if statements are incorrect. The correct syntax is as follows:

if(condition){code runs if condition is true}

NOT:

if(condition)
code to run

The code isn't too awful, however you may want to rename your variables. My advice is to switch to a do while loop. This lets you iterate code and the condition is checked after the code runs.

Using this loop allows you to specify more, and in my opinion is more versatile to work with. The loop is where I see most of the issues, unless you have some undefined variables elsewhere in the code.

Try to use escape keys, they are very efficient with ending lines. "\n" is way easier than endl, and you can put multiple escaped keys to skip multiple lines.

Comment: Braces on if statements are optional if it only contains a single statement

Comment: It is definitely not good practice to leave them dangling about.

Comment: That may well be, but still, your proposed answer claims, that the statements were *"incorrect"*. That's flat out wrong, and the voting system appears to work this time. And while this proposed answer fails to address the *real* issue, it may be best to just remove it altogether.